# Pandas: How to not be using the copy/view?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking all around and just cannot figure out how to rewrite this part of my program so it doesn't give me the "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" message.

here is how my code looks:

```
list_of_dataframes=[df1,df2,df3,df4]

empty_list=[]

for df in list_of_dataframes:
    df["new_column"]=df["column_x"].cumsum()
    empty_list.append(df)
```

So I am wanting to take the cumsum of "column_x" and the "new_column" will then show that value.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Since the original dataframes are changed in place, there is no need to create another list. At the end, `list_of_dataframes` and `empty_list` are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in place:

```
list_of_dataframes[:] = [df.assign(new=df['column_x'].cumsum())
                         for df in list_of_dataframes]]
```

Creating new list:

```
empty_list = [df.assign(new=df['column_x'].cumsum())
              for df in list_of_dataframes]]
```